# How to access last object inside nested array of objects and update its property without passing id or any parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access  last object inside  nested array of objects and change its property value, I don't know its id or any any other property value

```
const arr = [ {id: 1, comment:'parent 01', parentId:null, reply:true, children:[{id: 11, comment:'child', reply:true, parentId:1, children:[{id: 21, comment:'super child ', reply:true,parentId:11 }] }] }, {id: 2, comment:'parent 02', reply:true, parentId:null } ]
```

I want to access this below object and change its property value:

{id: 21, comment:'super child ', reply:true, parentId:11 }

```
// result should be:
{id: 21, comment:'super child ', reply:false, parentId:11 }
```

Comment: last children in nested array of objects

Comment: this is hard coded arr[0].children[0].children[0].reply = false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do it recursively and when the depth is greater than `0` and it doesn't have any children then need to modify the object(s).

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  comment: 'parent 01',
  parentId: null,
  reply: true,
  children: [{
    id: 11,
    comment: 'child',
    reply: true,
    parentId: 1,
    children: [{
      id: 21,
      comment: 'super child ',
      reply: true,
      parentId: 11
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  comment: 'parent 02',
  reply: true,
  parentId: null
}];


const build = (arr, depth) => {
  const nodes = [];
  arr.forEach((val) => {
    if (depth > 0 && !val["children"]) { //Base case
      nodes.push({ ...val,
        reply: false
      });
      return;
    }
    nodes.push(val["children"] ? { ...val,
      "children": build(val["children"], depth + 1)
    } : val);
  });

  return nodes;
}

console.log(build(arr, 0));
```